# Burn the [scripting-runtime] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [scripting-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting-runtime) tag has just five questions attached to it and not usage information to support it.

I found it had application to potentially be used in [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) with `filesystemobject`, but its usage across the five questions covers multiple languages, and the term overall seems to broad to be of great use (especially without usage information to guide it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have removed the tag from those 5 questions. The tag itself will be removed at 03:00 UTC, when the clean-up script runs, assuming no one add the tag back to a question.